# How can I hide bars with null values in C3?

Tags: c3.js

I have a C3 chart with data as JSON. The following is my data array consisting of the date category (x-axis) and ids with values (y-axis).

Notice that November's and December's second IDs are different than the second IDs for other data elements. Because I technically have 3 different IDs, C3 is trying to display my bar chart in groupings of 3, creating a separate bar for null values. I'm trying to hide these null values, so there's only ever 2 bars displayed for each date on my chart.

```
[
    {
      "category": "Jan 2019",
      "id1": 1200,
      "id2": 1400
    },
    {
      "category": "Feb 2019",
      "id1": 1000,
      "id2": 1200
    },
    {
      "category": "Mar 2019",
      "id1": 1050,
      "id2": 1100
    },
    {
      "category": "Apr 2019",
      "id1": 1000,
      "id2": 1050
    },
    {
      "category": "May 2019",
      "id1": 1250,
      "id2": 1300
    },
    {
      "category": "Jun 2019",
      "id1": 1450,
      "id2": 1500
    },
    {
      "category": "Jul 2019",
      "id1": 1700,
      "id2": 1900
    },
    {
      "category": "Aug 2019",
      "id1": 1650,
      "id2": 1850
    },
    {
      "category": "Sep 2019",
      "id1": 1450,
      "id2": 1750
    },
    {
      "category": "Oct 2019",
      "id1": 1400,
      "id2": 1500
    },
    {
      "category": "Nov 2019",
      "id1": 1300,
      "id3": 1500 // new id
    },
    {
      "category": "Dec 2019",
      "id1": 1350,
      "id3": 1200 // new id
    }
  ]
```

I attached an image below. Any help is appreciated!

[c3 chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgc3W.png)

Answer (score 1):

If this is the case that only one of id2 or id3 will be coming in data then group Id2 and ID3. so, it will take only one place.

You can even customize the colour for the respective data.